# Find the value of x in the diagram.

Tags: geometry, circles

Consider a circle whose radius is $5 m$. Let $AB$ be a chord in the circle of lenth $6 m$. And the two tangents at the points $A$ and $B$ are intersect at the point $P$.

In the following diagram, $CP=x$ and $AB=6$ and $OD=5$

How to find the value of $x$?

Diagram link: 
https://m.facebook.com/avinash.ncc.5/posts/1128939950552816

Comment: The diagram link did not work for me. I don't know if that's just me or not.

Comment: I was unable to upload photo directly. Thats why i was uploaded that image on my Facebook account and sent a link.....

Comment: Link not working

Comment: If you describe where the point **C** is, the rest of the configuration is understandable.

Comment: The point C is on the circle. And the point C is on the line OP where O is the center of the circle

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to see, that $OP$ and $AB$ are perpendicual and intersects $AB$ in two equal parts, ie. $|AD|=|BD|=3$.

After Pythagoras:
$$|AD|^2 + |OD|^2 = |OA|^2$$
$$3^2 + |OD|^2 = 5^2$$
we have then $|OD|=4$

Let $\alpha = ∠DOA $ and $|OP|=y$ Then
$$\cos \alpha = \frac{|OD|}{|OA|} = \frac{|OA|}{|OP|}$$
$$\frac{5}{y}= \frac{4}{5}$$

Then $y = \frac{25}{4}$, and $x=y-5=\frac{5}{4}$

Comment: Thank you..  The point C is on the circle thus x =(9/4)-1 = 5/4

Comment: @user322806 I've missed that point. I've made some corrections.